# Is "starboard" used for land vehicles?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Is it correct to use "starboard side" to refer to the "right-side" of a land vehicle (e.g. cars / trucks / lorries / motorcycles) ?

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/starboard) seems to accept specifically ships, boats, and aircrafts, but I've seen people using it to describe trucks ([link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3617/264), expand the comments).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that *port* and *starboard* are used in preference to *left* and *right* is to resolve ambiguity: does "right" mean on the right as I go forward, or on the right as I go aft?
In cars and trucks there is rarely an opportunity for ambiguity: you're expected to be in your seat, facing forward, at all times, so *right* and *left* are not ambiguous.  The exception is when you're performing maintenance, and then - to resolve ambiguity - the expressions *driver's side* and *passenger's side* are usually used, at least in the US.

(Question for the Brits and other right-side drivers out there: do your maintenance manuals refer to *driver's side* and *passenger's side*, or *left* and *right*, or *port* and *starboard*?  I've never been curious about this before, but suddenly I am.)

Comment: The most common terms I think are "offside" (right, or driver's side) and "nearside" (left, or passenger side). Certainly I've never heard "port" or "starboard" for a road vehicle.

Comment: @ColinFine - How odd that the terms are interpreted from the passenger's POV, rather than the driver's!

Comment: They're not relative to the passenger per se, but to the (left-hand) side of the road.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning in your first sentence. Even with *starboard* and *port* (or *larboard*), the terms are defined with you facing a certain way (toward the bow). The terms have more to do with how ships were steered and where goods were loaded. (See this [Online Etymology entry for starboard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=starboard&searchmode=none.)

Comment: @JLG - That's exactly the point: no matter where you are in the ship, or which way you're facing, *port*, *starboard*, *fore*, and *aft* are unambiguous (unless you've got turned around and lost in the dark of the hold, but in that case nothing would help.)  When you say *right* and *left*, however, you always have to qualify which way you're facing.  On land you could use North, South, East, West to express direction unambiguously, but... ships move, or so I'm told.

Comment: @MT_Head, Gotcha. I just wasn't following. Thank you for stating it again. Are these terms really used for aircraft, as the dictionary definitions state?

Comment: @JLG - I have no idea (not being a pilot) how _common_ those terms are in the aerospace industry as a whole... but I **have** seen seating schematics and cargo stowage instruction sheets that referred to "port" and "starboard".  Which is to say: I'm pretty sure that everybody will **understand** you if you use *port* and *starboard* w/r/t aircraft... but it may or may not be what the cool kids are saying.

Comment: @JLG - I've just done a bit of Googling, and I've found enough hits to reinforce (in my own mind, anyway) my last sentence above... and to even think that it might be what the cool kids are saying too.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen the terms used in relation to any land vehicle. Really they're only useful in something big enough to cause confusion between *my left* and *steering left*, so in effect ships.

Interestingly, I believe the Fleet Air Arm refer to left and right within their aircraft, versus port and starboard within the aircraft carrier. Whether this will change when they fly only from land I do not know.

Update: I find that in some military contexts regarding AFVs, *port* and *starboard* are used to reduce confusion. (e.g. 'Rifles through the starboard loopholes, aim 10 degrees left').  A few WW2 tanks had secondary turrets on each side, but these seem to have been called port/starboard and left/right indifferently. One 1940 vehicle had two forward and two aft sub-turrets, but since that was Russian (the T-35), we'll probably never know what they were called in English.